# Are "rusty" capacitors enough to cause a computer monitor to malfunction?

Tags: capacitor, repair

I have a computer monitor with an interesting issue: when I plug it into my laptop, it comes out of low-power mode and my work appears onscreen, but about a second later the screen goes black as it re-enters low power mode. Moveover, this only happens intermittently. The monitor will have periods where it works just fine, and stays on after turning on, and it will have periods where it encounters this malfunction every time it is plugged in.

I have another monitor of the same model that works just fine, and it doesn't seem to be the laptop, the wire or even the connection to the computer, as the other monitor shows the company logo for a few seconds upon being turned on, while the malfunctioning monitor doesn't make it that far.

Seeing as the warranty was exhausted, I opened it up to see if there were any clear indications of something looking out of place, and the only thing I noticed is that there are two 150µF electrolytic caps that appear rusty on top. Not quite exploded, but rusty-looking:
[image: Rusty capacitors]

It's possible that this "rust" is a leak, I'm not experienced enough to know.

Are these caps the likely cause of the issue?

Comment: "Not quite exploded" is not exactly good when it comes to capacitors.

Comment: If there are any more purple ones, even if they're not leaking yet, replace those also.

Comment: Probably one or both pins are gonna be embedded in a copper plane.  Those can be very difficult to work on, act like a big heatsink and pulls heat away from your joint, making it hard to melt the solder through.  You'll need a "good" temperature controlled soldering station and a nice fat chisel tip  - 15w pencil from Amazon will not cut it.

Comment: The fact that this screen controller board has this form factor, and uses SMD components at a relatively low population density together with it being a VGA board: yes, this board is fully affected by the [Capacitor Plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) rampanting throughout the early 2000s. Word of advise: that screen very likely isn't *that* nice that you'd want to keep it around. Especially: modern screens are not only nicer to the eyes, but also more power-efficient, so recycling this screen might be the environmentally wise thing to do.

Comment: By the time a cap visibly vents it has already lost at least 90% of it's rated value

Answer (score 9):

Those caps look like they’re failing. Notice that the ends are bulged out - the score marks on the caps provide a relief point for them to ‘vent’. And it looks like they’re doing exactly that. That ‘rust’ is electrolyte being expelled from the cap.

What to do then? Stop using this monitor - the caps may eventually short out and catch fire.

Now, as far as fixing it...

The placement of the caps looks like they’re on the power input side (DC in). That’s suspicious. It leads me to believe that their voltage was exceeded. Is the AC adaptor misbehaving? If so, more things may be fried than just the caps.

If you want to try to repair the board, make sure you understand that electrolytic caps come in different types. Try to find the exact type and cross that for replacement. In particular, note that low-ESR caps are used in power supplies due to the high dynamic currents they must deal with.

And, given the age of the monitor, it may have fallen victim to the ‘capacitor plague’ of the early 2000’s. More about that here:  https://www.theguardian.com/technology/blog/2010/jun/29/dell-problems-capacitors

Even then, check the AC adaptor to make sure it is working correctly. Test it with a load to ensure its voltage is in spec. It, too, may have the wonky caps.

At the end of the day, if it’s an old monitor it may not be worth the repair.

Comment: I'd recommend adding the explicit answer to OP's question, too (btw, nice, +1): yes, that means that they have very reduced functionality as capacitors (if any at all), and thus are a likely cause of malfunction.

Comment: The caps have failed long time ago. Stop using the monitor before it gets damaged beyond repair or damages your PC. It needs to be repaired if you want to continue using it, but depending on what the repair costs or can you do it yourself, can affect if it is more cost effective to buy a new display.

Comment: While a misbehaving external supply is certainly a concern worth considering, it may also be that the capacitors are low quality and under-rated or never achieved their claimed specifications.  That's been a widespread issue of long history not even confined to budget products but sometimes penetrating into the market of supposedly premium gear.

Comment: I added a Guardian link about capacitor plague. They don’t look like the typical off-brand types though (violet color, not black or green.)

Comment: Thanks! This is fantastic. The monitor is fairly new, but it's an old model that was discontinued shortly after I bought it. I'd definitely see it as worth fixing, so now the question becomes what I replace those 150µF caps with. It's not really a standard value, and I'm having trouble sourcing those without paying for just that value and shipping

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, you found the cause of the problems you're facing. Now it's time to hit the soldering iron and remove those caps before they destroy the board.